# Creating a DNS record with the port number

Tags: web-services, web, server, dns, hosting

I'm  hosting a website on my computer. I enabled port forwarding to port 8080 using the virtual server option ("The Virtual Server option allows you to define a single public port on your router for redirection to an internal LAN IP Address and Private LAN port if required.") so my website can be accessed by typing our router's IP address and then the public port redirecting to my internal IP (xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080). I also have a domain ready and I am trying to configure an A record in the DNS management panel. The target should be an IP address, but it says  invalid value in dnsrecord when I type the address and port. It probably doesn't accept the port, but if I don't specify the public port for my internal IP, the website can't be accessed. Any help?

Comment: You can not do what you want at the DNS level. The solution would have been `SRV` records but HTTP clients do not honor it. So you can not "direct" HTTP(S) traffic to anything else than port 80 or 443. Your solutions are either to hardcode the port number in the URL or install a proxy on ports 80/443 which will then connect to the appropriate high number port internally without the client knowing about it.

Comment: @markamery you edited my post and removed the answer. can you elaborate onwhy you did that? It prevents future troubleshooters from seeing a solution.

Comment: @user10833006 Sorry for not leaving an explanation at the time; I probably ought to have. Answers should go in the answer section. You're free post an answer to your own question, and to accept it. What you did here instead - editing the answer into the question - stops other users from commenting and and voting on it independently of the question. (It also has some potential to leave a reader confused about what's being asked.) I'm about to rollback again; however, feel free to ping me here further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default port is 80 so set port forwarding to that

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, your record should be an IP address and not IP:PORT. So just input the xx.xx.xx.xx address and it should work.

The TTL indicates how long the clients should consider the IP address corresponding to the DNS as valid.

The record type A indicates that it is an address record (returning an IP).

I don't know freenom, but I hope this helps you configuring your DNS record.

Comment: Thanks  for the help! In our home network we have many devices, so I set the port forwarding to be specifically to port 8080 for my computer. It doesn't work when I type only the normal IP address.

Comment: Agreed. But on the DNS level you only enter the IP address. Then you use the DNS like this: your-domain:PORT. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I set the public port to be 80 and the domain works fine for now. Are there any issues that could come from using port 80? Also for the record I have other family member's devices connected to the router.